# Fragment removed but still eats the back button

Tags: android

I have an activity to which I attach a fragment when a certain button is pushed:

```
ft.replace(R.id.change_user_fragment_container, changeClientFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Pressing the button a second time removes the fragment:

```
ft.remove(changeClientFragment).commit();
```

The fragment is removed in the sense that it is no longer displayed on the screen. However, when I press the back button after executing this sequence, I expect the activity to exit, but this does not happen. I have to press the back button a second time in order to exit the activity. 
Can anyone explain this and tell me how to get the behavior I expect?

Comment: use ft.popBackStack() method.

Comment: Almost, @longkai... ft is FragmentTransition, and I needed FragmentManager. But If you post that as an answer, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### forgive my incorrectness at first...

the fragment transaction, `add`, `remove`, `replace`, provides a way to change the layout stuff on screen(one activity) dynamically. But if you want to keep a fragment in the back stack, that it means, when the user press the back button, it will return the last screen(still in one activity), you call `FragmentManager.addToBackStack(tag)`. After this method return, what you do will take palce in another fragment transaction, which means it won' t affect the previous backstacked fragment transaction. So, instead using `remove` to remove the fragment, you need to call `FragmentManager.popBackStack` manually(which perform like the user press the back button) to pop the backstacked fragment.

#### in short, `FragmentManager.addToBackStack(tag)` and `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` are the opposite.